# Floating divs the same height

Tags: jquery, css, css-float, height, fluid-layout

I would like to make floating divs the same height. I use JavaScript in my current solution although if anyone knows a way to do it in CSS only that would be even better.

**Current solution:**
I grab and store the value of the tallest div then apply it to the others. 
Now the issue is that I'm working on a fluid/responsive layout and when resizing the browser window the content extends/reduces but the div's height won't follow. For instance the text will jump outside its container and making the window smaller.

[jsfiddle of my code](http://jsfiddle.net/9A9DV/8/)

```
var tallest = 0;
var articles = $(".article");

articles.each(function(){
   if ($(this).height() > tallest) {
        tallest = $(this).height();
   }
});
```

articles.height(tallest);

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `display: table` and `table-cell`.

```
.container {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    display: table;
}

.article {
    display: table-cell;
    /* float: left; if required */
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 15px;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

You can still float them if required.

You need to use `border-collapse` and `border-spacing` to get a gap between them:

```
.container {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap grid classes.

Comment: That important detail should be included with your question. I don't work with Bootstrap so don't know how it affects my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a (hacky) css way. Plus, I dont know how it works and dont remember where i read it.

Anyway, here it goes:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/vqG2L/

HTML

```
<div class="columns-wrapper">
    <div class="column">

    </div>
    <div class="column">

    </div>
    <div class="column">

    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

CSS

```
.columns-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.column {
    background:#ccc;
    padding-bottom:999em;
    margin-bottom:-999em;
    float:left;
    width:33%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some other trick.

The fiddle to your example extended:

http://jsfiddle.net/LTds9/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container ovrfl prel">
    <div class="article prel">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p>Maecenas adipiscing ullamcorper sagittis. Nam luctus consequat convallis. Mauris hendrerit a purus commodo semper. Ut id fringilla nibh. Suspendisse massa velit, dapibus sed elit sit amet, posuere tincidunt.</p>
        <div class="pabs"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="article prel">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
        <p>Maecenas adipiscing ullamcorper sagittis. Nam luctus consequat convallis. Mauris hendrerit a purus commodo semper. Ut id fringilla nibh. Suspendisse massa velit, dapibus sed elit sit amet, posuere tincidunt lacus. Donec quis dui non sem iaculis venenatis. Curabitur vitae luctus lectus, sed pellentesque tellus. Vestibulum semper eu tortor semper ornare.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="bott pabs"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.article {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 15px;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    padding: 20px;
}

.article p, .article h2 {
    color: black;
}

.prel{
    position:relative;
}
.pabs{
    position:absolute;
}

.container .pabs{
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:-1;
    height:300px;
    background-color:inherit;
}
.ovrfl{
    overflow-y:hidden
}

.container .bott{
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Hopefully this will work nicely with bootstrap grid classes. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Sure, no big deal. I thought it's visible by the code and the fiddle example. The tricks is an absolute div is used as background extension